# Mixing table header <th> and table data <td> cells in a single table row <tr>

Tags: html-table, w3c

I have a set of survey questions each of which I am arranging in a single row table. I want the first entry to serve as a prompt and have been using <th> for that cell, as in:

```
<table style='width:100% table-layout:fixed;border-collapse: collapse;'>
  <tr>
    <th style='width:40%'>
      <b>How long were you on active surveillance?</b>
    </th>
    <td style='width:10%;'>f3_watchtime_num</td>
    <td style='width:5%'></td>
    <td style='width:50%;>f3_watchtime</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It seems to work OK but I have some reservations and questions about mixing <th> and <td> cells in a single <tr>:

1. Is this HTML5 Standards compliant? (Is there a W3C document that allows or prohibits this practice?)
2. Are there any downsides to this practice?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*1.  Is this HTML5 Standards compliant? (Is there a W3C document that allows or prohibits this practice?)*

W3C `tr` reference says it's content model can contain:

> **Content Model:**
>   Zero or more td, th, and script-supporting elements
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element

While your usage isn't very common, there isn't anything in W3C that forbids it.

*2. Are there any downsides to this practice?*

As for the use of `th` and `td` together, its accepted by W3C provided they are children of a `tr` element.
However, if you are displaying tabular data, (i.e. your survey results are data) using a table is fine.  If you are using the table for layout purposes, you should use a CSS based layout instead.

Comment: Even more, in the same doc: **Tag omission in text/html:
A td element's end tag may be omitted if the td element is immediately followed by a td or th element, or if there is no more content in the parent element...**  So a th can follow a td (strange as it seems)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the reference. The code example following "The scope IDL attribute " is even stranger!

Comment: Nobody here say that tables for layouts is a crap? I think OP is quitting from the discussion because he don't want to learn to layout with correct properties and tags

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation of W3C is avoid to use tables for layouts. It is valid only for displaying ordered data, but that's not your case. You can achieve the same with `<div>` and will be semantically correct.

Other thing is your question about mixing. I think if you don't write `<tbody>` and  `<thead>` tags, you don't separate the content for the headers in the table, so that's correct because there aren't `<td>` tags inside a `<thead>` and there aren't `<th>` tags inside a `<tbody>`.

However, it's better practice if you don't use tables for this purpose.

Comment: I think W3C says its fine even in the `thead` and `tbody`. `tr` is a valid child for those tags, and `th` and `td` are both valid children of `tr`.  So you could end up with a `th` being a grandchild of `tbody`.  At least I dont see anything in the docs that forbids it.  https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-thead-element  and https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element

Comment: Do not forbids, but tables for layouts is a sacrylege. Even you share a TABULAR DATA URL!!!!